# Потокобезопасная обертка над объектом

Tags: c++, многопоточность, c++11, инспекция-кода

Есть ли минусы, которые могут заставить не использовать подобные обертки.
Также подскажите, есть ли уже что-то подобное в stl или boost.
Вот накидал пример:

*SafeRef:*

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>

template<typename RefType>
class SafeRef
{
public:

    SafeRef(std::mutex &mutex, RefType ref) : m_reference(ref), m_mutex(mutex)
    {
        m_mutex.lock();
    }
    SafeRef(SafeRef &&other)
        : m_mutex(other.m_mutex), m_reference(other.m_referance)
    {
    }

    RefType get() const { return m_reference; }

    ~SafeRef() { m_mutex.unlock(); }
private:
    std::mutex &m_mutex;
    RefType m_reference;
};
```

*Тестовый код:*

```
class SomeObj
{
public:
    SafeRef<const std::vector<int>&> getVector() const
    {
        return SafeRef<const std::vector<int>&>(m_mutex, m_vector);
    }
    void reserve(int n)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex>(this->m_mutex);
        m_vector.reserve(n);
    }
    void addElement(int i)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex>(this->m_mutex);
        m_vector.push_back(i);
    }
private:
    mutable std::mutex m_mutex;
    std::vector<int> m_vector; //Большой вектор, копирование очень затратно
};

void write(SomeObj &obj)
{
    obj.reserve(500);
    for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
    {
        obj.addElement(i);
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
    }
}

void read(const SomeObj &obj)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
        auto v = obj.getVector();
        std::cout << v.get().size() << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    SomeObj obj;
    std::thread thread1(&write, std::ref(obj));
    std::thread thread2(&read, std::ref(obj));
    thread2.join();
    thread1.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Проблема этого подхода в том, что *потокобезопасность намного сложнее*.

Вы не можете просто так сделать объект потокобезопасным, защитив все операции мьютексом. К примеру, у вас есть обёртка над стеком, дававйте посмотрим тогда на код

```
SupposedlySafeStack<int> s;
// ...
if (!s.is_empty())
    s.pop();
```

Проблема здесь в том, что между выполнением `if (!s.is_empty())` и `s.pop();` стек вполне мог стать пустым.

Для хорошего потокобезопасного стека нужен другой набор операций. Например, атомарный `bool try_pop(T&)` и `push_range(Iterator begin, Iterator end)`. *Потокобезопасность нужно планировать на уровне внешнего интерфейса класса.*

То же относится к доступу по индексу к `std::vector` и так далее.
Поэтому обёртки, которые оборачивают все публичные функции, непригодны: они лишь создают ложное чувство безопасности!

А обёртка на целый объект уже существует, это `std::lock_guard`.

---

Кроме того, обычно вам нужно сделать потокобезопасным не один объект, а *группу* объектов и их отношения между собой. Например, у вас есть очередь и стек, как в [алгоритме сортировочной станции](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8); нет смысла иметь отдельно защищённый стек и отдельно очередь, потому что при этом они могут рассогласоваться во время вашей операции! Например, если вы переносите все элементы из стека в очередь, то после удаления всех элементов из стека перед добавлением в очередь в стеке могут образоваться новые элементы, и инвариант вашего алгоритма нарушится.

Вам придётся заводить явный мьютекс, и защищать не объекты, а *ваши операции с объектами*.

Comment: Подскажите, как можно эффективно и безопасно работать с массивом, более сложным, по сравнению со стеком. К примеру, с вектором. Или скиньте ссылку, литературу, etc

Comment: @EgorMoroz: Я не знаю подходящей литературы, набивал шишки сам на личном опыте разбора крешей в собственном коде. Вам нужно продумать, какая группа объектов образует логическую сущность, и защищать операции, преобразующие эту группу, а не индивидуальные объекты.

Comment: @EgorMoroz, посмотрите [Concurrency in Action](http://scrutator.me/post/2014/10/03/cpp_concurrency_in_action.aspx), насколько я помню, она должна быть на русском.